# How to have a fixed navbar and the content is below it

Tags: html, css, position, navbar, fixed

I have a Fixed navbar:

```
    .navbar
{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #2327fc;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed; 
}

.navObject
{
    display: block;
    padding:1vh;
}

.navLink
{
    display:block;
    background-color: #79aada;
    padding:0.55vh;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #7c9ff9;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 3vh 3vw;
}
```

I want the div to be below the navbar. Is there a way to do this without guessing the margin needed.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <body>
                <article>
                    <div>
                        <ul class ='navbar'>

                        <li class = 'navObject'><a href="(a link)" class="navLink" >Link 1</a></li>
                        <li class = 'navObject'><a href="(a link)" class="navLink" >Link 2</a></li>
                        <li class = 'navObject'><a href="(a link)" class="navLink" >Link 3</a></li>

                         .... more navbar content       
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        ...below content
                    </div>
    ..closing tags
```

Currenly the content in the below div is being shown from the top of the html page and the navbar is covering some of this content.

I want the content to be below the navbar. (But also fixed - i understand putting it fixed takes it out of the flow, but is there a workaround?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: sticky; top: 0;` instead of fixed.

Comment: This solution is not working. When I scroll the navbar goes away

Comment: I have tried to add some more context (html code) to my question

Comment: Check this out - https://codepen.io/saranya-mohan/pen/bGzLgzL?editors=1100

Comment: 2 things:
1. `top` is an mandatory prop to be used along with `position: sticky`
2.  class='navbar'` should be parallel to the UI element which you want to next to it.

I've made it work in the above codepen. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had to add the class to the div and not just the ul.